# past simple instead of past perfect in sentences including "until"

Tags: tense

> 1. Until I went into the army, I was an introverted person for a long time.

I'm not comfortable sayin like this. rather I would say like this.

> 2. Until I went into the army, I had been an introverted person for a long time.

I don't know why but I feel more comfortable saying #2. How about you guys?

Comment: It's a good question, but I think you'd better make more general titles for your questions so other people can search and find. for example something like *past simple instead of past perfect in sentences including "until"*

Comment: Here's smoe more advice: ask a question that will invite answers. "How about you guys?" makes this little more than a poll. What are we supposed to say? "Yup, me too"? In your last 20 questions, only 16 have had net upvotes. That should tell you something: you need to work harder on posting substantive questions, and that goes beyond fixing your titles.

Comment: By the way, I agree that #2 reads better, but the difference is only very slight and only noticeable when I really carefully analyze it.